# Talend greenplumRow error handling

Tags: etl, talend, greenplum, hawq

I want to create views in greenplum HAWQ using a simple talend job, that would basically have a fileinput that contains all the views then I need to execute the CREATE VIEW script.

Since these views (50-60.000) come from an oracle system I need to find the ones that we were unable to create.

Here's a mock up for my problem:
[image]

I have a view already in the DB, and I want to create it 3 more times. This would obviously fail.

Here's the output:

```
Exception in component tGreenplumRow_2
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "ad_apps_dependencies" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1592)
.--------------.
|  tLogRow_4   |
|=------------=|
|componenterror|
|=------------=|
|componenterror|
'--------------'

.-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------.
|                                                                                  tLogRow_5                        |
|=----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------=|
|result                                               |result1                                                      |
|=----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------=|
|ERROR: relation "ad_apps_dependencies" already exists|CREATE VIEW SYSTEM.AD_APPS   AS SELECT * FROM APPLSYS.AD_APPS|
'-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------'

.------------.
| tLogRow_6  |
|=----------=|
|subjobError |
|=----------=|
|Subjob Error|
'------------'
```

I want to have this output 3 times, as I try to run 3 times the query. (In the final version I'd create another file that contains only the queries that failed, so we can fix it later, but this is a crucial point.)

As a workaround:
I could move this tRow -> OnError -> FixedFlow -> FailedViews part into a different job, but thats not an elegant solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing here. Why are you trying to create a view 3 times when you know that it will fail on repeated attempts?

Comment: I want to do an error handling when a SQL fails. The easiest to reproduce the error is to run it 3 times -> I want to catch the error 3 times.

Comment: So what's the question? You want to log when a SQL error fails? That should be written to logs without needing you to catch the error and then throw it to logs anyway as you can see with the very start of your output.

Comment: I have a file that contains 98523 SQL, if the first one fails -> the whole execution stops. I expect that half of the SQL will fail, and I want to examine / re-execute them. If I want to execute ALL the SQL-s again all of them fails.

Comment: If you don't tick the "die on error" box and the data from the SQL query isn't needed downstream in the job then it should just carry on processing and the logs will have all of the failed queries. You can actually see that in your set up because the tLogRow5 has some data and that subjob is only executed on subjob okay from where the SQL error happened.

Comment: If I don't tick the "die on error" I need to check the CONSOLE LOG. I want to catch these errors inside my job.  My workaround is the following: I created a JOB for the tRow - onComponentOk -> errorhandling part, then I can call iterate -> tRunJob (without die on error) This way I can have a CSV file with all the SQL-s that I couldn't execute. But I don't find this elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with tJavaFlex. It works for Greenplumrow as well!!! In the below exmaple I execute a query in tOracleInput_6:

```
"SELECT count(*) FROM "+((String)globalMap.get("ora_sch.SCHEMA_NAME")) + "." + ((String)globalMap.get("ora_tab.TABLE_NAME"))
```

I am not sure about query result. It might fail (eg:someone just dropped the table) therefore i use tJavaFlex+iterate connection! The resulting code generated try {...} catch block.

In below case i iterate over tables of a schema and count the rows in every table. I collect the exceptions into a java hashmap. (the hashmap is in the context, but that's another story)

[image]

```
tJavaFlex Begin code:
try{

tJavaflex main code:
// here is the main part of the component,
// a piece of code executed in the row
// loop
System.out.println(((String)globalMap.get("TYPE"))+" SELECT count(*) FROM "+((String)globalMap.get("ora_sch.SCHEMA_NAME")) + "." + ((String)globalMap.get("ora_tab.TABLE_NAME")));


tJavaFlex1 End code:
// end of the component, outside/closing the loop
} catch (Exception e) {
//put 
((Map<String, String>)context.EXCEPTIONS).put(
  ((String)globalMap.get("TYPE"))+((String)globalMap.get("ora_sch.SCHEMA_NAME"))+"_"
  +((Integer)globalMap.get("tFlowToIterate_8_CURRENT_ITERATION")).toString(),
((String)globalMap.get("ora_sch.SCHEMA_NAME"))+","
+ ((String)globalMap.get("ora_tab.TABLE_NAME")));

//print some debug message
System.out.print(((String)globalMap.get("TYPE"))+" ### SQL Exception at ");
System.out.print("Iteration Number: "+((Integer)globalMap.get("tFlowToIterate_8_CURRENT_ITERATION")).toString()+","+((String)globalMap.get("ora_sch.SCHEMA_NAME"))+","+ ((String)globalMap.get("ora_tab.TABLE_NAME")));
System.out.println(" ###");
//e.printStackTrace();
}
```